# Export and Import a Site Page using PowerShell

Tags: 2010, powershell, export, sitepages

I am familiar with how to export/import a site using PS. My question is, is it possible to do the same operation with a Site Page? For example, SiteA/default.aspx contains 2 Site Pages called ToDoList (SiteA/SitePages/ToDoList.aspx) and ThingsDone (SiteA/SitePages/ThingsDon.aspx). Is it possible to export/import the 2 Site Pages to another Site in a different Site Collection?

Answer (score 2):

yes in SharePoint you can export and import file or specific object.

```
Export-SPWeb -identity "http://sitename1" -ItemUrl "/pagename.aspx"  -Path "c:\pagename.aspx" 

Import-SPWeb -identity "http://sitename2" -Path "C:\pagename.aspx"
```

Comment: It has successfully exported and imported but the web parts contained in the Site Page are rendering with errors. "Web Part Error: List does not exist. The page you selected contains a list that does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user." What was I supposed to look out for?

Comment: Check if any list or library must be there if any code refers to that.